# Problem with Cassandra TOKEN paging mechanism

Tags: java, cassandra

Our data set has a lot of duplicate partition keys. We are using the TOKEN method to paginate through the data. If the rows with the duplicate keys are split across a page we don't get the remainder of the duplicates on the next call.

For example assume we have the following keys: 1 2 3 5 5 5 6 7 8 and we have a limit of 5 rows per query. The first query "**select * from table where TOKEN(id) > TOKEN('') limit 5;**" returns 1 2 3 5 5 as expected. The second query "**select * from table where TOKEN(id) > TOKEN('5') limit 5;**" returns 6 7 8. This is not the desired behavior, we want the second query to return 5 6 7 8. Thinking about this, it is obvious why this happens: "**(TOKEN(id) > TOKEN('5')**" fails if id == 5

Are we doing something wrong or is this just the way it works? We are using the latest Java driver, but I don't think this is a driver problem since the Golang driver also exhibits this behavior

We've (mostly) worked around the problem by either dropping any duplicated records at the end of the row set (the 5 5 in the example) or dropping the last record (to cover the case where the last record is duplicated in the second record set). This fails if the record set is all duplicates. Obviously larger limits reduces this edge case, but it doesn't seem safe to use in a production environment.

*** EDITED ***

The TOKEN method is recommended in a lot of pages both here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere on the web. But obviously it doesn't work :-(

@alex:

Thanks for your reply. The example was just that, a simplified example of the issue. In reality we have 30 million rows and are using a limit of 1000. When the table was first designed years ago the designer didn't understand how the partition key works so they used the user ID as the partition thus giving us 30 million partitions. We believe that this is at least contributing to our excesive repair times (currently at 12 hours for the cluster). We need to copy the entire table into a new one with a different partition key (in a live production environment) to resolve the partition key issue. This page https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/paging/ seems to be a better solution.

@Nadav:

Thanks for your reply. Simply removing the limit will cause the request to time out in multiple layers of our software. The DataStax page above seems to be the best solution for us.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up several things - in Cassandra data is organized inside partitions, and you can get data by partition key, or perform a range scan using the `token` function. The results of the query could be delivered to applications by [pages](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/paging/) - you can specify the fetch size (although 5 is quite small), fetch one page, process, fetch next, process, ..., until the result set is exhausted.

In your case, the page size doesn't match the result set size - you have 6 results there, and the next result set (for `token(id) > token(5)`) has only 3 rows. I don't know a solution that works out of box (except `select * from table`, but it may timeout in case if you have a lot of data). In your case I would better go with bigger ranges (for example, whole token range), and page results inside it (without using `limit`), and then handle the case when you need to switch to the next token range, and you have some rows that are left from previous token range.

I have an [example of Java code](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/jdtest1/TokenRangesScan.java) that is performing effective scan of the all token ranges, similar to what the Spark connector is doing. The main trick there is to route request to the node that holds the data, so it will read data directly from the node itself, without need to reach other nodes (if you're reading with `LOCAL_ONE`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't, and can't, use token ranges and LIMIT to page through results, and you found out yourself that it doesn't work - because LIMIT cuts off some of the result, and you have no way to continue.

Instead, Cassandra gives you a separate **paging** feature: You make a request, get the first 1000 (or whatever) rows and **also** a "cookie" with which you can resume the query to get the next page of results. Please refer to your favorite driver's documentation on the syntax of using Cassandra **paging** in your favorite language. It's not "LIMIT" - it's a separate feature.

Splitting up a large query into multiple token ranges still has its uses. For example, it allows you to query the different ranges in *parallel*, since different token ranges will often come from different nodes. But still, you need to query each range to completion, using paging, and cannot use "LIMIT" because you can't know how many results to expect from each range and need to read them all.